# Gitlab CI: how to load vars from JSON file

Tags: asp.net, json, docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I'm creating ASP.Net Core applications using Gitlab CI and docker-in-docker.
So at first stage I build Dockerfiles and push them in repo, at the second stage I apply yamls to deploy from repo to cluster.

K8S doesn't allow to run containers at port 80 (in my configuration), so I need to expose ports for Dockerfiles.

What I want to do - load correct port numbers from `appsettings.json` (AspNet config file) in GitLab CI/CD - I don't want to hardcode that values in Gitlab job or in Gitlab Variables.

At the current moment I'm going this way `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build:
  image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/dockerhub/library/docker:20.10.11
  stage: build
  services:
    - ${CI_REGISTRY}/dockerhub/library/docker:20.10.11-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker build
      -f ./MyApp.Api/Dockerfile
      --build-arg PORT=5076 .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myapp:${tag}
```

I hardcoded `--build_arg` to expose correct port.

**How to read it value from JSON file?**

Json file looks like this:

```
{
  "MyApp": {
    "ConnectionString": "Host=host;Port=5432;"
  },
  "ClientBaseUrls": {
    "MyApp": "http://my-serv:5076/api",
  }
}
```

Also I can add additional var to JSON, for example: `PORT=5076` but still can't figure out how to read this value in GitLab CI.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in a previous job to read from appsettings.json , save them in a script that exports these variables, use this script as artifact and run it in your build job so that env variables are available in your build stage.

You stated that you can add additional vars, so lets assume your .json looks like this:

```
   {
      "port" : "5678",
      ...
    }
```

Then your gitlab-ci.yml could look like this:

```
stages:
  - variables
  - build

variables:
  stage: variables
  image: ubuntu
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y jq 
  script:
    - export PORT=$(cat appsettings.json | jq '.port' )
    - echo "export PORT=$PORT" >> vars.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vars.sh

build:
  image: ${CI_REGISTRY}/dockerhub/library/docker:20.10.11
  stage: build
  services:
    - ${CI_REGISTRY}/dockerhub/library/docker:20.10.11-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - . ./vars.sh
  script:
    - docker build
      -f ./MyApp.Api/Dockerfile
      --build-arg PORT=$PORT .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/myapp:${tag}
```

Comment: If you have jq available in your  `${CI_REGISTRY}/dockerhub/library/docker:20.10.11` image or can install it, then of course can remove the workaround with the script and just use  `export PORT=$(cat appsettings.json | jq '.port' ) `